# How to execute Python script from electron using a button click?

Tags: javascript, python, anaconda, electron

try.html file:-

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" class="btn" id="processbtn" value="Process" onclick="get_tt()" />
    <script src="try3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

try3.js file:-

```
function get_tt() {
    document.getElementById("processbtn").value = "Hang on..."
    var python = require("python-shell")
    var path = require("path")

    var options = {
        scriptPath: path.join(__dirname, ''),
        pythonPath: 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Anaconda3/python'
    }

    var f = new python("hello.py", options);
    f.end(function(err, code, message) {
        document.getElementById("processbtn").value = "Done";
    })
}
```

The python code is not executing using this code. The value of button changes to Hang on... ,and remains in the same state.

Comment: Hi KU. What is the content of the `hello.py` file? Since you have a listener for the `end` event it could be that your script is not terminating properly and you never get the end event. Also, you can log to a file or something od the sort from the python file to make sure it's being called. Do you see any errors on the console?

Comment: @limoragni hello.py :-  import sys
print('Hello from Python!')
sys.stdout.flush()